# Is there a generalization of the twin prime conjecture to rings or certain rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, twin-primes

The question's in the title.  For instance, if $R$ contains $2$ then there are an infinite number of pairs of prime principal ideals $(p),(q)$ such that $p = q + 2$.  I just made that up and it's probably not true.  But to give you an idea....

Comment: For a general ring of algebraic integers $\mathcal O$, you have an embedding  of $\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow \mathcal O$, so you could have the same conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\Bbb Z[x]$, both $(x+k)$ and $(x+k+2)$ are prime for every integer $k$.